# How to zip the selected files of a HTML form

Tags: php

I have PHP page which lists some songs based on a criteria such as album year or something. I just placed a checkbox near to every song. When a visitor selects some check box and press submit button the form sends each value to a php file. In the PHP file the values are stored in an array.

```
$files_to_zip=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['song'];i++)
$files_to_zip[]=$_POST['song'][$i];

//'song' is the name of the checkbox in the HTML form
```

The problem is the PHP file does not create the zip file with the code i wrote.

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = true) {
//if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
//vars
$valid_files = array();
//if files were passed in...
if(is_array($files)) {
//cycle through each file
foreach($files as $file) {
//make sure the file exists
if(file_exists($file)) {
$valid_files[] = $file;
}
}
}
//if we have good files...
if(count($valid_files)) {
//create the archive
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
return false;
}
//add the files
foreach($valid_files as $file) {
$zip->addFile($file,$file);
}
//debug
//echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

//close the zip -- done!
$zip->close();

//check to make sure the file exists
return file_exists($destination);
}
else
{
return false;
}
}

$files_to_zip = array();
foreach($_POST['song'] as $fileabc)
{
$files_to_zip[]=$fileabc;
}
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-archive.zip');
if($result==true)echo "Success"; else echo "failed";
```

This is the entire code I use in the PHP.

If I set the value for $files_to_zip dynamically such as,

```
$files_to_zip=array('link1','link2','link3'..)
```

it works properly.

What is the bug in my code?

Comment: Letting a user submit the path to a file, without checking it and/or validating it: That looks like a security problem.

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['song'];i++) 
$files_to_zip[]=$_POST['song'][$i];` is the same as `$files_to_zip=$_POST['song']`, is not it?

Comment: I am confused, your code is redundant and please, improve your syntax, you are using something like this: "if(myvariable != true) return false;" The correct way is "return myvariable;" (will return true or false) that's all.

Comment: @PLB: Yes, Obviously. But both not working!!

Comment: @OscarJara: the issue is not the last line. The main issue is Zip file is not getting created and the reason is associated in array() syntax and I am not able to choose the right way of using it

Comment: @JaredFarrish: security problem in the sense? Do you mean the path to the file may be wrong?

Comment: @SuryaS `var_dump($files_to_zip)` and see if is the same format as `$files_to_zip=array('link1','link2','link3'..)`

Comment: A malicious user could submit `../../config.xml` or something else, and your script would not know if that were valid or not. You should always validate user input before working with it in any way, and the data submitted should fit only what you are expecting. You're inherently trusting that no malicious user will attempt to exploit your script. Definitely bad practice and a serious security hole.